# haar training got stuck at stage 6

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

I use 1000 positive images and 4000 negative images with 20 stage.
It got stuck at stage 6.
Can anyone help me please

```
PARAMETERS:
cascadeDirName: classifier/
vecFileName: samples1.vec
bgFileName: ./non-face/negative.txt
numPos: 1000
numNeg: 4000
numStages: 20
precalcValBufSize[Mb] : 1024
precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] : 1024
stageType: BOOST
featureType: HAAR
sampleWidth: 19
sampleHeight: 19
boostType: GAB
minHitRate: 0.995
maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5
weightTrimRate: 0.95
maxDepth: 1
maxWeakCount: 100
mode: BASIC
```

Comment: Bring your hit rate down to lik e0.8

Comment: I will give it a shot!!! Any other suggestion???